Strange difference of result when in a for loop in R
The first part of the context is not the important part, but here it is:
So I'm trying to fit a matern model with the variofit function in R for a school project. When trying fix.kappa == FALSE for it to find itself the best value for kappa failed for some reason. Therefore I tried to find it manually, by trying a series of values for kappa, and searching manually for one that would minimise the MSE.
Here is the strange part :
I made this code that calculates the the MSE for each value of kappa between 0.5 and 50:
kappa_list = seq(0.5, 50, length.out = 50)
  MSE_list = c()
  for(kappa_temp in kappa_list){
    
    variofit_temp = variofit(
      emp_variog2,
      fix.nugget = FALSE, nugget = nugget_0,
      fix.kappa = TRUE, kappa = kappa_temp,
      ini.cov.pars = c(part_sill_0,range_0),
      cov.model = "matern",
      messages = F
    )
    
    MSE_list = append(variofit_temp$value, MSE_list)
  }
    
  plot(kappa_list, MSE_list)

Then I remembered that kappa could take a tinier value than 0.5, so I re wrote the code:
kappa_list = seq(0.1, 50, length.out = 50)
  MSE_list = c()
  for(kappa_temp in kappa_list){
    
    variofit_temp = variofit(
      emp_variog2,
      fix.nugget = FALSE, nugget = nugget_0,
      fix.kappa = TRUE, kappa = kappa_temp,
      ini.cov.pars = c(part_sill_0,range_0),
      cov.model = "matern",
      messages = F
    )
    
    MSE_list = append(variofit_temp$value, MSE_list)
  }
    
  plot(kappa_list, MSE_list)

But I realised the value it shows for kappa = 50 is different for this loop than the previous one. I thought at first that it was just a precision error, because the MSE is very sensitive around 50, so I looked if the last value of the sequence was really exactly 50 or 50.00000001, but it seems that it's exactly 50.
I tried some other things, but figured out that "simulating" the loop by playing each line one by one, strangly didn't the problem ! That's the weird part. Here's the code that a played in the console :
> min_kappa = 0.1
> kappa_list = seq(min_kappa, 50, length.out = 5)
> kappa_temp = kappa_list[length(kappa_list)]
> kappa_temp
[1] 50
> variofit_temp = variofit(
+     emp_variog2,
+     fix.nugget = FALSE, nugget = nugget_0,
+     fix.kappa = TRUE, kappa = kappa_temp,
+     ini.cov.pars = c(part_sill_0,range_0),
+     cov.model = "matern",
+     messages = F
+ )
> variofit_temp$value
[1] 1721348178
> variofit_temp = variofit(
+     emp_variog2,
+     fix.nugget = FALSE, nugget = nugget_0,
+     fix.kappa = TRUE, kappa = 50,
+     ini.cov.pars = c(part_sill_0,range_0),
+     cov.model = "matern",
+     messages = F
+ )
> variofit_temp$value
[1] 1721348178
> kappa_list = seq(min_kappa, 50, length.out = 5)
>   print(paste0("kappa_list = ", kappa_list))
[1] "kappa_list = 0.1"    "kappa_list = 12.575" "kappa_list = 25.05"  "kappa_list = 37.525" "kappa_list = 50"    
>   MSE_list = c()
>   for(kappa_temp in kappa_list){
+     set.seed(123)
+     print(paste0("kappa_temp = ", format(kappa_temp, digits = 22, scientific = FALSE)))
+     
+     kappa_temp <- round(kappa_temp, digits = 1)
+     
+     variofit_temp = variofit(
+       emp_variog2,
+       fix.nugget = FALSE, nugget = nugget_0,
+       fix.kappa = TRUE, kappa = kappa_temp,
+       ini.cov.pars = c(part_sill_0,range_0),
+       cov.model = "matern",
+       messages = F
+     )
+     
+     MSE_list = append(variofit_temp$value, MSE_list)
+   }
[1] "kappa_temp = 0.1000000000000000055511"
[1] "kappa_temp = 12.57499999999999928946"
[1] "kappa_temp = 25.05000000000000071054"
[1] "kappa_temp = 37.52499999999999857891"
[1] "kappa_temp = 50"
>   
>   print(paste0("MSE for kappa = ", kappa_list[length(kappa_list)],
+                " is ", MSE_list[length(MSE_list)]))
[1] "MSE for kappa = 50 is 21781768624.2714"

Here is the full code :
# ---- Libraries ----
library(ggplot2)
library(geoR)
library(sp)

# ---- Data importation ----
parana = structure(
  list(
    east = c(
      402.95294, 501.70493, 556.32618, 573.40431, 
      702.42284, 668.54416, 435.8477, 434.01245, 432.46225, 162.14585, 
      169.47663, 717.84675, 713.34332, 726.66302, 618.46885, 661.88082, 
      506.71667, 561.7874, 585.63949, 531.71056, 308.97183, 306.10469, 
      150.12196, 155.3399, 620.00181, 475.05766, 366.87187, 479.49527, 
      615.72353, 599.07288, 566.56758, 484.6613, 445.54377, 498.29528, 
      477.94465, 353.18336, 338.52463, 267.23204, 676.87847, 538.88998, 
      340.96468, 203.93695, 254.26247, 719.46243, 768.50871, 721.65469, 
      687.75359, 599.06043, 541.89327, 449.6865, 357.51524, 222.33953, 
      297.32299, 184.17268, 401.98944, 365.36206, 331.68065, 294.95009, 
      674.31593, 518.6908, 562.79775, 399.91232, 309.69511, 308.21592, 
      397.59888, 206.29791, 289.38003, 246.80304, 279.55302, 231.82964, 
      245.59459, 410.80902, 400.01532, 405.11185, 422.47533, 457.73378, 
      388.47179, 299.07823, 320.4695, 317.7274, 328.1532, 341.96468, 
      346.05942, 371.75809, 377.09969, 395.46678, 244.79297, 232.08612, 
      212.36295, 250.92841, 249.11474, 262.98869, 264.83559, 277.18097, 
      267.48289, 287.42489, 291.21859, 296.594, 295.11083, 211.66139, 
      189.31521, 165.97002, 164.28177, 184.98705, 711.89977, 749.59433, 
      702.73299, 650.76351, 640.73071, 600.65702, 421.28296, 451.44393, 
      419.33262, 377.71707, 357.49565, 372.27262, 287.35834, 285.6835, 
      224.32153, 218.99256, 262.66451, 217.24028, 212.63015, 249.35852, 
      245.90862, 251.23978, 197.7439, 172.85298, 187.83331, 568.34196, 
      541.68923, 493.34111, 471.68756, 445.03235, 479.99208, 333.22941, 
      400.32814, 343.6607, 320.24316, 331.8482, 235.32685, 226.53333, 
      692.54456
    ),
    north = c(
      164.52841, 428.771, 445.27065, 447.04177, 
      272.2959, 261.6707, 286.54044, 317.90506, 288.37001, 286.29984, 
      334.53158, 181.56741, 214.88336, 207.27952, 127.43265, 128.81455, 
      212.86691, 138.89773, 212.59809, 131.62153, 181.97682, 148.69468, 
      162.12624, 154.86652, 112.64927, 83.6448399999998, 92.2122400000002, 
      461.96806, 400.63795, 456.12037, 445.22857, 423.22788, 400.9933, 
      426.92592, 356.79285, 446.50166, 381.74695, 373.39454, 254.18138, 
      308.77851, 271.01967, 309.41998, 240.19632, 177.84707, 199.12352, 
      209.20941, 187.56295, 210.66083, 185.11924, 196.16437, 188.1198, 
      154.59123, 176.26524, 211.03701, 70.3728200000003, 77.4256500000004, 
      110.26775, 113.43465, 185.89772, 378.94032, 362.2088, 354.61628, 
      375.85998, 359.22457, 443.1808, 359.3556, 370.04023, 374.89923, 
      345.88871, 450.35979, 445.05926, 242.10715, 339.85273, 338.04194, 
      262.48003, 306.9234, 299.16275, 285.24334, 329.84407, 279.96009, 
      256.09127, 271.01967, 313.5301, 278.71589, 247.38436, 267.83959, 
      297.28745, 343.23287, 311.44174, 238.28897, 339.84732, 321.6157, 
      312.41223, 281.21777, 255.20257, 273.991, 246.34864, 340.60144, 
      325.80878, 263.38789, 281.3855, 267.90686, 267.86614, 323.79426, 
      124.40728, 175.47115, 179.95796, 178.79807, 180.7536, 199.57391, 
      177.57037, 174.02255, 223.70296, 179.08881, 189.96577, 223.34289, 
      170.56964, 170.54282, 139.84991, 154.52067, 146.1385, 158.17924, 
      217.21353, 142.19763, 147.67415, 131.14844, 205.80201, 192.283, 
      198.18379, 114.86877, 120.51877, 98.4340199999995, 103.94229, 
      105.70264, 118.72419, 119.52053, 70.36, 84.566, 93.49421, 97.3436600000001, 
      92.0340700000003, 114.02601, 170.87504
    ),
    data = c(306.09, 200.88, 
      167.07, 162.77, 163.57, 178.61, 301.54, 282.07, 319.12, 244.67, 
      233.31, 224.46, 206.12, 248.99, 237.87, 222.87, 263.1, 236.91, 
      247.01, 240.58, 304.28, 351.73, 277.92, 323.08, 253.32, 315.33, 
      379.94, 197.09, 199.91, 167, 182.88, 197.1, 257.5, 205.16, 224.07, 
      212.5, 242.08, 247.79, 187.27, 222.54, 313.6, 269.92, 321.69, 
      208.89, 238.62, 248.76, 193.48, 240.48, 265.56, 302.13, 335.41, 
      330.87, 329.49, 262.81, 365.88, 359.08, 344.59, 366.1, 201.84, 
      218.27, 200.38, 229.4, 235.07, 236.25, 228.82, 258.12, 232.17, 
      248.17, 240.66, 184.59, 165.46, 320.31, 232.8, 266.27, 301.1, 
      244.78, 248.57, 299, 269.49, 300.89, 311.81, 317.34, 286.93, 
      306.64, 349.09, 289.11, 280.49, 237.11, 269.68, 307.47, 253.57, 
      226.71, 299.69, 266.62, 331.46, 270.67, 321.15, 258.2, 288.85, 
      255.76, 264.77, 271.76, 313.63, 252.94, 246.75, 215.95, 299.71, 
      203.4, 209.47, 185.63, 304.3, 320.05, 273.01, 295.62, 334.95, 
      350.18, 291.35, 319.57, 367.32, 332.04, 332.18, 323.82, 334.22, 
      345.33, 345.24, 383.13, 348.67, 282.54, 291.07, 245.42, 291.63, 
      288.5, 314.65, 331.85, 305.43, 285.05, 359.51, 356.82, 372.56, 
               413.7, 412.44, 400.96, 199.37
    )
  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -143L)
)

parana_borders = structure(
  list(
    east = c(
      670.204875, 663.718688, 656.066688, 649.971438, 
      642.634563, 635.271688, 628.742125, 622.755875, 617.270813, 610.457, 
      604.42175, 600.262, 592.621, 585.444625, 581.92875, 574.871563, 
      567.99075, 565.6725, 560.5745, 553.86975, 546.261688, 542.435063, 
      537.837375, 534.376563, 529.409438, 528.1835, 520.268156, 513.789781, 
      509.833156, 505.105344, 499.977219, 491.988906, 486.094406, 478.869313, 
      474.045719, 470.925344, 473.2195, 476.876406, 476.248156, 468.888031, 
      462.077594, 457.88275, 453.517656, 448.93925, 440.925281, 433.288844, 
      425.385563, 417.613313, 409.689906, 402.012969, 395.090313, 388.905156, 
      381.620781, 373.674125, 365.810969, 358.028781, 350.718188, 343.347406, 
      336.159188, 329.237156, 321.329844, 313.663188, 305.80225, 298.281313, 
      290.861594, 284.227281, 277.077844, 271.504219, 263.543781, 256.520563, 
      248.8575, 241.656109, 235.520094, 231.700766, 226.547563, 225.8555, 
      219.657406, 216.403594, 215.340656, 216.788484, 213.318719, 212.552734, 
      206.664047, 201.807359, 199.6235, 192.151453, 187.422156, 188.983141, 
      184.399016, 178.437156, 174.949359, 170.373547, 163.837438, 157.839297, 
      155.134688, 150.051703, 144.086359, 138.815359, 138.297594, 137.987281, 
      144.653203, 149.781453, 148.382547, 153.388125, 159.686078, 155.62975, 
      153.212984, 154.687313, 157.737141, 163.658594, 160.675313, 164.211328, 
      172.130047, 165.728922, 158.935609, 157.750344, 159.271844, 158.399938, 
      155.783297, 157.487594, 158.247594, 162.589, 165.391719, 157.077922, 
      157.754734, 160.412781, 162.614203, 166.648797, 163.022797, 163.530688, 
      166.652172, 171.481313, 171.281031, 165.928656, 165.506375, 165.3565, 
      167.316813, 170.03325, 167.977563, 163.491438, 161.473719, 163.997516, 
      170.930609, 178.861531, 185.087641, 190.730766, 190.762938, 193.086672, 
      195.451828, 198.341609, 200.613078, 203.828609, 204.428203, 208.680922, 
      214.333047, 221.180953, 224.122406, 226.760719, 229.690422, 231.72975, 
      231.220078, 235.038641, 240.402063, 247.119406, 254.061875, 261.190891, 
      268.550156, 275.370188, 282.111844, 287.672, 293.985563, 301.211688, 
      307.937906, 315.517, 323.409656, 331.151406, 336.672156, 343.911, 
      351.417813, 356.621688, 362.441, 367.828219, 368.792531, 375.514781, 
      381.666813, 383.534469, 387.002438, 394.258938, 396.523313, 396.644688, 
      402.613531, 408.970906, 416.527875, 423.576406, 430.054938, 437.537875, 
      444.892563, 452.482813, 459.560219, 464.211406, 465.268031, 467.336875, 
      465.45875, 472.983781, 476.725063, 480.198531, 478.720594, 479.167094, 
      480.899469, 482.783188, 483.727938, 483.194875, 485.376531, 488.530688, 
      491.747375, 494.156156, 499.878813, 496.505469, 499.45075, 502.862656, 
      495.062781, 491.5965, 498.709813, 504.852094, 500.144813, 500.993125, 
      505.134438, 503.235969, 506.228938, 508.160219, 509.2235, 503.473406, 
      509.178344, 516.034031, 520.147219, 521.236875, 527.753063, 531.995563, 
      538.783625, 545.707125, 553.139188, 560.024625, 566.74675, 574.19725, 
      582.02375, 589.887375, 597.229313, 603.811188, 605.871, 612.286938, 
      613.857063, 621.287813, 628.639063, 631.817438, 637.492438, 634.20475, 
      629.226563, 630.906875, 638.968875, 632.025, 625.798625, 631.953125, 
      632.155188, 639.860125, 641.00775, 637.589125, 637.24325, 636.01825, 
      638.107625, 641.851813, 642.569438, 647.145438, 646.820625, 642.397875, 
      646.79425, 651.9535, 655.33225, 660.207125, 666.556125, 668.464313, 
      671.055375, 674.749375, 682.068125, 678.8675, 676.1265, 672.481563, 
      670.703063, 672.062563, 679.603063, 686.332625, 694.170375, 700.403375, 
      707.086875, 715.055063, 722.802563, 730.246063, 738.165688, 745.08375, 
      751.146, 748.617188, 746.678813, 746.024563, 742.908813, 745.792625, 
      750.472063, 754.7605, 756.962, 764.113563, 766.416875, 773.6025, 
      779.524438, 780.54775, 781.245688, 782.124438, 785.844, 786.494, 
      793.205188, 798.625563, 793.336563, 788.13475, 783.140375, 779.378563, 
      777.683813, 780.69875, 787.14325, 779.648813, 772.613438, 769.153125, 
      769.227688, 765.929875, 763.41925, 758.943313, 758.803438, 755.02475, 
      758.635313, 755.889125, 749.726063, 741.674063, 735.94675, 729.9425, 
      729.948, 732.53975, 724.347438, 732.07725, 739.425688, 747.238313, 
      749.815563, 757.045125, 765.36825, 761.700813, 756.485438, 752.37975, 
      748.731938, 744.853563, 738.498438, 733.378375, 731.44225, 739.654313, 
      743.952688, 740.586188, 734.3525, 726.756313, 718.759688, 710.763438, 
      702.864375, 695.90125, 688.046, 680.367938, 670.204875),
    north = c(111.761, 
      107.051, 105.242, 100.7915, 97.993, 101.1545, 105.5405, 110.7495, 
      116.397, 120.5795, 119.667, 121.898, 119.9675, 120.177, 115.782, 
      119.532, 115.8975, 110.499, 117.333, 120.929, 121.4415, 119.9445, 
      117.39, 110.527, 104.375, 97.7945, 98.896, 97.3895, 94.0785, 
      94.73, 98.2715, 98.26, 93.482, 90.0065, 83.768, 76.4215, 69.7315, 
      62.9205, 55.255, 52.0755, 49.4895, 46.7695, 53.727, 59.958, 58.8065, 
      60.247, 60.1965, 58.7055, 58.782, 61.107, 64.9245, 70.0245, 72.88, 
      73.6025, 74.997, 75.2305, 77.7445, 78.171, 80.7555, 84.688, 84.1965, 
      83.564, 83.2995, 82.2695, 80.292, 84.5905, 87.9925, 93.4435, 
      94.249, 90.7505, 88.96, 92.3015, 96.4505, 103.246, 109.2565, 
      116.906, 122.0885, 128.354, 136.198, 143.92, 151.001, 158.5445, 
      163.667, 166.2495, 167.25, 169.1685, 165.457, 173.248, 174.298, 
      169.808, 168.851, 169.669, 165.8305, 161.0635, 154.883, 161.614, 
      164.554, 167.945, 176.129, 183.5995, 179.9475, 181.639, 189.343, 
      190.8625, 188.6405, 192.2815, 196.7395, 201.929, 202.4355, 198.6235, 
      201.474, 207.0945, 206.12, 207.3115, 205.5975, 210.408, 213.2685, 
      216.1175, 220.7955, 222.779, 224.8275, 225.788, 228.3695, 228.715, 
      233.218, 242.7005, 248.682, 249.457, 253.9695, 258.6515, 265.281, 
      265.8665, 266.8735, 272.053, 279.341, 286.609, 293.7815, 301.3105, 
      309.0375, 315.479, 323.254, 330.385, 334.1935, 335.4215, 340.129, 
      345.8245, 353.308, 360.851, 368.452, 375.9125, 383.465, 390.732, 
      398.7125, 405.3755, 411.065, 415.045, 422.3715, 429.8395, 437.277, 
      444.9855, 453.0285, 459.9115, 465.8625, 470.151, 474.1165, 477.7425, 
      480.8905, 485.017, 489.3505, 495.0075, 499.934, 503.1085, 499.2055, 
      496.7625, 495.3895, 496.865, 500.318, 497.055, 497.705, 494.4745, 
      496.3685, 491.1985, 491.6935, 489.49, 493.9795, 501.523, 507.9295, 
      504.9965, 497.152, 503.3365, 502.907, 498.0905, 497.7135, 496.94, 
      493.1595, 492.287, 489.9165, 492.5375, 493.548, 490.967, 483.0055, 
      482.201, 490.2815, 491.8335, 484.8545, 482.781, 474.8165, 473.0705, 
      480.3425, 472.1715, 468.8685, 476.651, 481.32, 474.7985, 475.4645, 
      479.503, 474.766, 470.4505, 467.3145, 465.864, 463.654, 461.1125, 
      459.3925, 454.5375, 452.687, 443.8865, 444.3065, 451.4485, 457.7515, 
      463.096, 470.414, 475.6315, 476.1755, 473.357, 467.075, 459.4815, 
      459.3755, 464.782, 464.875, 465.694, 462.5555, 464.8, 463.1885, 
      462.725, 461.2715, 462.521, 465.8655, 464.5585, 460.5085, 456.086, 
      449.595, 446.604, 444.8285, 437.737, 432.025, 425.496, 422.555, 
      420.4055, 419.884, 416.7505, 413.4625, 414.2685, 411.1705, 411.021, 
      403.435, 401.2055, 400.3325, 397.1535, 394.517, 389.9, 382.0995, 
      375.437, 367.535, 361.227, 355.1195, 349.3295, 342.219, 335.8645, 
      330.8, 324.334, 317.356, 310.5265, 307.0365, 300.0215, 292.5305, 
      285.4165, 277.625, 269.8635, 267.0335, 269.963, 269.5365, 273.576, 
      269.09, 269.743, 269.0615, 267.9115, 267.6705, 267.2245, 261.5795, 
      255.2725, 247.9015, 240.0395, 232.673, 226.0275, 222.804, 230.096, 
      237.04, 239.545, 247.0055, 246.4635, 241.737, 235.974, 228.906, 
      221.1565, 214.5615, 208.1565, 204.8215, 205.266, 199.1955, 193.133, 
      186.8895, 180.5855, 187.108, 194.386, 199.101, 198.6915, 194.921, 
      197.2955, 205.304, 200.563, 199.8925, 205.232, 196.9885, 193.748, 
      188.6695, 181.1865, 182.4225, 182.355, 185.664, 190.334, 185.579, 
      179.157, 179.706, 177.326, 175.5195, 176.2825, 172.8805, 171.5365, 
      170.572, 165.084, 159.1015, 152.2355, 145.1195, 138.108, 141.5515, 
      139.683, 135.9955, 136.1905, 133.044, 125.3875, 126.208, 124.2705, 
      124.561, 124.8235, 124.122, 121.1025, 122.3335, 121.7645, 111.761
    )
  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -369L)
)




# ---- Variogram ----
geodat_parana = as.geodata(parana, coords.col = 1:2, data.col = 3)

dist_mat = dist(parana[1:2])
min_dist = min(dist_mat)
max_dist = 500
breaks = seq(from = min_dist, to = max_dist, length.out = 50)

emp_variog = variog(geodat_parana, breaks = breaks, option = "bin")


# ---- Matern Variofit ----
# initial values
nugget_0 = 0
sill_0 = 7000
part_sill_0 = sill_0 - nugget_0
range_0 = 400

for(min_kappa in c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)){
  kappa_list = seq(min_kappa, 50, length.out = 5)
  print(paste0("kappa_list = ", kappa_list))
  MSE_list = c()
  for(kappa_temp in kappa_list){
    set.seed(123)
    print(paste0("kappa_temp = ", format(kappa_temp, digits = 22, scientific = FALSE)))
    
    kappa_temp <- round(kappa_temp, digits = 1)
    
    variofit_temp = variofit(
      emp_variog,
      fix.nugget = FALSE, nugget = nugget_0,
      fix.kappa = TRUE, kappa = kappa_temp,
      ini.cov.pars = c(part_sill_0,range_0),
      cov.model = "matern",
      messages = F
    )
    
    MSE_list = append(variofit_temp$value, MSE_list)
  }
  
  print(paste0("MSE for kappa = ", kappa_list[length(kappa_list)],
               " is ", MSE_list[length(MSE_list)]))
  
  plot(kappa_list, MSE_list, ylim = c(1.5e+09, 2e+10))
}

Full output :
[1] "kappa_list = 0.1"    "kappa_list = 12.575" "kappa_list = 25.05"  "kappa_list = 37.525" "kappa_list = 50"    
[1] "kappa_temp = 0.1000000000000000055511"
[1] "kappa_temp = 12.57499999999999928946"
[1] "kappa_temp = 25.05000000000000071054"
[1] "kappa_temp = 37.52499999999999857891"
[1] "kappa_temp = 50"
[1] "MSE for kappa = 50 is 21781768624.2714"
[1] "kappa_list = 0.2"   "kappa_list = 12.65" "kappa_list = 25.1"  "kappa_list = 37.55" "kappa_list = 50"   
[1] "kappa_temp = 0.2000000000000000111022"
[1] "kappa_temp = 12.64999999999999857891"
[1] "kappa_temp = 25.09999999999999786837"
[1] "kappa_temp = 37.54999999999999715783"
[1] "kappa_temp = 50"
[1] "MSE for kappa = 50 is 13067343235.6359"
[1] "kappa_list = 0.3"    "kappa_list = 12.725" "kappa_list = 25.15"  "kappa_list = 37.575" "kappa_list = 50"    
[1] "kappa_temp = 0.2999999999999999888978"
[1] "kappa_temp = 12.72500000000000142109"
[1] "kappa_temp = 25.15000000000000213163"
[1] "kappa_temp = 37.57500000000000284217"
[1] "kappa_temp = 50"
[1] "MSE for kappa = 50 is 7316447596.3402"
[1] "kappa_list = 0.4"  "kappa_list = 12.8" "kappa_list = 25.2" "kappa_list = 37.6" "kappa_list = 50"  
[1] "kappa_temp = 0.4000000000000000222045"
[1] "kappa_temp = 12.80000000000000071054"
[1] "kappa_temp = 25.19999999999999928946"
[1] "kappa_temp = 37.60000000000000142109"
[1] "kappa_temp = 50"
[1] "MSE for kappa = 50 is 4028582940.74542"
[1] "kappa_list = 0.5"    "kappa_list = 12.875" "kappa_list = 25.25"  "kappa_list = 37.625" "kappa_list = 50"    
[1] "kappa_temp = 0.5"
[1] "kappa_temp = 12.875"
[1] "kappa_temp = 25.25"
[1] "kappa_temp = 37.625"
[1] "kappa_temp = 50"
[1] "MSE for kappa = 50 is 2728655320.43029"


Please post the output value you got for each loop and for a single-value run (all when kappa_temp or equivalent is set to 50 .     Did you try each loop setup more than once to verify no random glitch error?    What happens if you insert, say,  25 into the kappa_list in each setup?

@user2554330 Yep sorry, I added it

@CarlWitthoft I added the output for the full program, but I already put the output for the single value run. Yes I didn't try to see if there was randomness, but I added a set.seed(123) in the code.

The problem is with your reporting.  When you print MSE for kappa = 50 is 21781768624.271 you're actually printing the MSE value for some other kappa value, because you're putting new values at the start of the list, not the end of the list, in this expression:
MSE_list = append(variofit_temp$value, MSE_list)

To fix things, just use
MSE_list = c(MSE_list, variofit_temp$value)

(or use append() in place of c(), they do the same thing here.)

I've recommended that the question be closed as being about a typo.  If it doesn't get closed and you want to delete it, leave a message here and I'll delete my answer, or SO might not let you delete it.

Yep I need you to delete your answer please to be able to delete my post
